# Clickable image - android

Tags: android, image, click, clickable-image

How do i make a image clickable? I have tried some ways, but without success. 
Here's the last code i tried (it's clickable but gets error):

```
    ImageView btnNew = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newbutton);
    btnNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            // do stuff
          }

        });
```

and here's the part from xml:

```
    <ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/tbnewbutton" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/newbutton"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="clickImage"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

When running this code, and clicking the image i get this error:

> 01-24 19:14:09.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1461): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method clickImage(View) in the activity

**HERE'S THE SOLUTION:**

The XML:

```
    <ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/tbnewbutton" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/newbutton"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="clickNew"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null" />
```

The code :

```
    public void clickNew(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Show some text on the screen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As other said: make this an `ImageButton` and define its onClick attribute

```
<ImageButton
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="left"
     android:onClick="scrollToTop"
     android:src="@drawable/to_top_button"
/>
```

The image is here encoded in a file res/drawable/to_top_button.png.  If the user clicks on the button, the method `scrollToTop()` is called.  This method needs to be declared in the class that sets the Layout with the `ImageButton` as its content layout.

```
public void scrollToTop(View v) {
    ...
}
```

Defining the OnClick handler this way saves you a lot of typing and also prevents the need to anonymous inner classes, which is beneficial for the memory footprint.

Comment: Ok, this one works, but now my image is inside a button.. So it's braking my layout. To fix this i added the line android:background="@null" into the xml and all works perfect!

Comment: The correct background to use is `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"`.

Answer (score 3):

Does an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) do what you want?

The error message you get implies that you do not have a method in your activity that matches your onClick handler.

You should have something like `clickImage(View view)` in your activity with the click handling implementation.

Comment: I tried with clickImage(View view) but doesn't work, cause of the OnClickListner.. If an imagebutton is transparent and will show the image only (no button), i can use it.

Comment: Oh, if you are explicitly setting an on click listener in onCreate, you should not have a onClick attribute in your layout.

Comment: I have tried removing android:onClick="clickImage" from the code, and the result is that nothing at all happens when clicking.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the ImageButton class...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've set the onclick method to call "clickImage" when the image is clicked in your XML, but you haven't created a clickImage method in your code.  You shouldn't need to set the onclick listener at all.  Just implement the method from your XML and you should be set.