# How to enable the "vibration and tactile feedback" in the code?

Tags: android, android-vibration, android-14

When the Android phone system is upgraded to Android 14, the "Vibration and Touch Feedback" option is turned off by default. At this time, if the developed Android application has vibration function, vibration is ineffective. However, when "Vibration and Touch Feedback" is turned on, the vibration function returns to normal.
How to enable the "vibration and tactile feedback" function in the code?

Comment: You shouldn't.  Users turn off that option because they don't like it.  That would override their decision not only for your app, but for every app on the phone.  That just about assures they'll uninstall your app as soon as they figure out who did it.  If your app does not ABSOLUTELY need it to work, honor their preference.  If it does, handle the vibration yourself with explicit vibration calls rather than use the system touch feedback, that should still go through I beliece.

Comment: Related/unclear if you've seen: [Android; detect if the Vibrate setting in the device is on or off, esp for the case when it rings but does not vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32709260/295004) and the comments in this answer about [haptic feedback in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58415783/295004)

Comment: hi, @GabeSechan, i have handle the vibration in the code:`val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator val pattern = longArrayOf(100, 400) vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1)` but it did not work