# Android: phone ignores correct vibration code

Tags: android, android-vibration

**Setting.**
I would like to make my phone vibrate when a button is clicked. I use the code of [SO question: How to make an Android device vibrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate?rq=1).

The code to let the phone vibrate:

```
@Override
public void onClick (View view)
{
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) MyActivity.this.getSystemService (Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    if (vibrator.hasVibrator()) {
        Log.v ("Can Vibrate", "YES");
    } else {
        Log.v("Can Vibrate", "NO");
    }
        vibrator.vibrate (1000);
    }
```

I also added the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

to the manifest file.

**Problem.**
The phone does not vibrate at all upon button click. Other apps on my phone make the phone vibrate.

**Log messages.**

```
xxxx V/Can Vibrate﹕ YES
xxxx V/Vibrator﹕ Called vibrate(long) API - PUID: 10060, PackageName: de.creamin.vibratetest
xxxx V/Vibrator﹕ vibrate - PUID: 10060, PackageName: de.creamin.vibratetest, ms: 1000, mag: -1
```

**Phone.**
Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300), Android 4.3

**Question.** What is going on here? Do I have to configure my phone somehow to accept the vibration code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out why my phone does not vibrate. Under menu item

`phone settings > My device > Sound > Vibration intensity`

you can adjust the vibration intensity for `Incoming call`, `Notification` and `Haptic feedback`. The settings of `Notification` has been set to zero. Hence, my phone did not vibrate. After setting that slider to a value greater than zero, my phone vibrates on clicking the button in my app.

Answer (score 1):

No need to pass MyActivity.this may be. Try:

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)
```

Comment: I tried that but with no change in the behavior. The phone is still not vibrating.