# App that should vibrate the phone crashes on Eclipse and cannot instantiate activity

Tags: android, eclipse, vibration

I don't know why but I am getting this ![Log Cat][1] when trying to make an app that vibrates the phone after pressing a button, following the class [Udemy Vibrate App](https://www.udemy.com/learn-by-doing-android-for-beginners/#/lecture/285885). I have aready tried to clean, close the program and check if Android Private Libraries is selected (it is). I also gave permission to the phone to vibrate in the manifest file.

```
12-15 16:36:37.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 16:36:37.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24903): Process: com.example.vibrate, PID: 24903
12-15 16:36:37.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24903): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate 
activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vibrate/com.example.vibrate.Vibrate}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.vibrate.Vibrate" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.vibrate-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-
lib/com.example.vibrate-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

This is the program:

```
package com.example.vibrate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class VibrateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button vibrateButton;
    private Button rhythmButton;
    private Button stopVibrationButton;

    private Vibrator vibrator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vibrate);

        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        vibrateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vibrate);
        rhythmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rhythm);
        stopVibrationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_vibration);

        vibrateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        rhythmButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopVibrationButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.vibrate:
            vibrator.vibrate(1000);
            break;

        case R.id.rhythm:
            long[] pattern = { 250, 500 };
            vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
            break;

        case R.id.stop_vibration:
            vibrator.cancel();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vibrate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Vibrate"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate)

Comment: Not yet switched to Android Studio ?

Comment: Your issue is not related to Vibration....so change Question title....

Comment: @MD I just changed the title. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MD I actually know hoew to make it vibrate, if you check the code I did exactly what they say in the link you passed.

Comment: @DonChakkappan I am downloading it now. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Activity` name is different from your manifest declaration.Its not about Vibration

You need to decalre your `Activty` in manifest like

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.vibrate.VibrateActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

instead of

```
<activity
        android:name=".Vibrate"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: @LeonardoSaturninoFerreira whats the new exception??