# Vibration on every second using timer in Android

Tags: android, timer, android-vibration

I am writing an Android application in which I am using timer android. It is working perfectly, now I want to make it like it should vibrate on every second until the completion of the time.

My code is given below:

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    TextView textViewTime;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_responders_timer);
            btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CanelButton);
            textViewTime  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
            textViewTime.setText("10"); 
            textViewTime.setTextSize(120);
            final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(10000,1000);
            textViewTime.setTextSize(120);
            timer.start();

            btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            });

        }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            textViewTime.setTextSize(50);
            textViewTime.setText("Completed.");

            }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textViewTime.setText(""+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me Google that for you: 'android vibrate' =  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate Seriously, learn to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write

`import android.os.Vibrator;
 ...
 Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 // Vibrate for "whatever_time_u_want" milliseconds
 v.vibrate(whatever_time_u_want);`

give permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`