# How to enable vibration when screen timeout occurs?

Tags: android, vibration

I want the device to start vibrating for some amount of time when screen timeout option enables(when the light dims, before the screen shuts off).I know how to set up both functions individually, but I can't seem to manage to get them in the right order for this to work, so I need your help. Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Use this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/a/17066803/2563355

Answer (score 0):

Use the vibrator class to initiate vibration

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            vib.vibrate(5);
     }
}, 30000); //30 sec
```

Edit:

Don't forget as I did to declare in the app manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: I've done that, but i need it to trigger when screen timeout starts (e.g. after 30 seconds).