# How to make phone vibrate from Qt Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm deploying Android app using Qt.

I'd like to make the phone vibrate. So I try to execute [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950364/3336423) using `QAndroidJniObject`.

Java code:

```
import android.os.Vibrator;
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(500);
```

C++ Qt code:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");

if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    QAndroidJniObject serviceName = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.content.Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE");
    if ( serviceName.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject vibrator = activity.callObjectMethod("getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;",serviceName.object<jobject>());
        if ( vibrator.isValid() )
        {
            vibrator.callMethod<void>("vibrate", "(J)V", 1000);
        }
        // vibrator is actually not valid!
    }
}
```

`vibrator.isValid()` returns false and I cannot figure out why....It's not my first time trying to do this kind of stuff, but here, I can't make it work.

Note: My app has `android.permission.VIBRATE` set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could gather from [the documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.2/qandroidjniobject.html#fromString), `QAndroidJniObject::fromString` returns an object wrapping a Java string with the contents that you gave to `fromString`.

So what you're doing right now is as if you had done the following in Java:

```
Object vibrator = getSystemService("Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE");
```

when what you really want is:

```
Object vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

So instead of using `QAndroidJniObject::fromString` you probably ought to be doing something like this:

```
QAndroidJniObject serviceName = 
    QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField<jstring>(
        "android/content/Context",
        "VIBRATOR_SERVICE");
```

It's possible that you need to delete the local reference to `serviceName` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I cannot make this piece of code compile with Qt 5.2.1. Error is `undefined reference to '_jstring* QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<_jstring*>(char const*, char const*)`

Comment: Oops. That should probably be `getStaticObjectField` instead of `getStaticField`.

Comment: By the way, the phone does not vibrate :-( even if vibrate code is now reached and executed. Any idea?

Comment: vibrate call profile has to be changed from `(I)V` to `(J)V`. Edited the original post.