# Can't make the phone play sound nor vibrate using Qt for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qandroidjniobject

I'm deploying an Android application using QtCreator.

I'd like to play a sound and make the phone vibrate to notify the user that something bad happened. I use QAndroidJniObject to call SDK functions.

I could not make anyone work.

**For "vibrate":**

```
// java code:
// import android.os.Vibrator;
// Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// v.vibrate(500);
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    QAndroidJniObject serviceName = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField<jstring>("android/content/Context","VIBRATOR_SERVICE");
    if ( serviceName.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject vibrator = activity.callObjectMethod("getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;",serviceName.object<jobject>());
        if ( vibrator.isValid() )
        {
            vibrator.callMethod<void>("vibrate", "(I)V", 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

`vibrator.callMethod` is reached (thanks to [Michael help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29644593/3336423)) but the phone does not vibrate (note that my application has `android.permission.VIBRATE`)

**For "play sound", I tried both:**

```
// java code:
// Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
// Ringtone ring = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
// ring.play();
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    jint notifcationType = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/media/RingtoneManager", "TYPE_NOTIFICATION");
    {
        QAndroidJniObject notification = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/media/RingtoneManager", "getDefaultUri", "(I)Landroid/net/Uri;", notifcationType);
        if ( notification.isValid() )
        {
            QAndroidJniObject ring = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/media/RingtoneManager", "getRingtone", "(Landroid.content.Context;Landroid/net/Uri;)Landroid.media.Ringtone;",activity.object<jobject>(),notification.object<jobject>());
            if ( ring.isValid() )
            {
                ring.callMethod<void>("play", "()V");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**and**

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    jint notifcationType = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/media/RingtoneManager", "TYPE_NOTIFICATION");

    QAndroidJniObject notification = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/media/RingtoneManager", "getDefaultUri", "(I)Landroid/net/Uri;", notifcationType);
    if ( notification.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject player = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/media/MediaPlayer", "create", "(Landroid.content.Context;Landroid/net/Uri;)Landroid.media.MediaPlayer;",activity.object<jobject>(),notification.object<jobject>());

        if ( player.isValid() )
        {
            player.callMethod<void>("start", "()V");
        }
    }
}
```

In both case, last function is not reached because objects are not valid (nor player, nor ring are valid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. vibrate() takes long as an argument and not int.
2. Always use slashes to separate package and class names in you jni calls.

try:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
//    QAndroidJniObject activity = QtAndroid::androidActivity(); // Req. Qt 5.3
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    // This gets the string value of the VIBRATOR_SERVICE field.
    QAndroidJniObject serviceField = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField<jstring>("android/content/Context", "VIBRATOR_SERVICE");
    if ( serviceField.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject vibrator = activity.callObjectMethod("getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;",serviceField.object<jobject>());
        if ( vibrator.isValid() )
        {
            // Note that vibrate takes a long and not an int as argument.
            vibrator.callMethod<void>("vibrate", "(J)V", 500);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    jint notifcationType = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/media/RingtoneManager", "TYPE_NOTIFICATION");
    QAndroidJniObject notification = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/media/RingtoneManager", "getDefaultUri", "(I)Landroid/net/Uri;", notifcationType);
    if ( notification.isValid() )
    {
        // Note that package and class names needs to be separated with '/' and not '.'
        QAndroidJniObject ring = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/media/RingtoneManager",
                                                                       "getRingtone",
                                                                       "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/net/Uri;)Landroid/media/Ringtone;",
                                                                       activity.object<jobject>(),
                                                                       notification.object<jobject>());
        if ( ring.isValid() )
        {
            ring.callMethod<void>("play", "()V");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You fixed it! Thanks a lot.