# How can you make a phone vibrate on button press?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to create an Android on click function that will make the phone vibrate for 5 sec.

Comment: @Inbar: in general, downvotes are not mean. They are a message that the voter did not think the question featured any research - see the alt-text on the down arrow.

Answer (score 6):

Try this out:

```
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 v.vibrate(5000); // 5000 miliseconds = 5 seconds
```

And add the permision in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Read more here please, this is the duplicate and easily to be found:
[How to make an Android devide vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate)

Comment: As the method "v.vibrate(long)" is deprecated, here's a new way to implement for newer Api Level: 

val vibrator = context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as? Vibrator
vibrator?.takeIf { it.hasVibrator() }?.let {
 val duration: Long = 5000 // 5 seconds
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
  val vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(duration, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
  vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect)
 } else {
  vibrator.vibrate(duration)
 }
}