# How to make an Android device vibrate when device show result on screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, vibration, android-vibration

Now, I want to make the device vibrate when device show result on screen

some parts of **MainActivity.java**

```
public void onResult(String result) {
    String tres = "\n";
    try {
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject j1 = j.getJSONObject("status");
        int j2 = j1.getInt("code");
        if(j2 == 0){
            JSONObject metadata = j.getJSONObject("metadata");
            if (metadata.has("custom_files")) {
                JSONArray musics = metadata.getJSONArray("custom_files");
                for(int i=0; i<musics.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tt = (JSONObject) musics.get(i); 
                    String title = tt.getString("title");
                    tres = tres + (i+1) + ".  Title: " + title + "\n";
                }
            }
        }else{
            tres = result;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        tres = result;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mResult.setText(tres);
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// Vibrate for 1 seconds
v.vibrate(1000);
```

**Note:**
Don't forget to include permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Vibrate for 100 milliseconds

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(100);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950364/1979882

Answer (score 0):

use this code when you receive results

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(100);
```