# How to enable vibration from Android 7+

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat, android-hardware

I have to enable vibration only on devices with Android 7+. In previous versions we could simply do:

```
AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
aManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Permission **android.permission.VIBRATE** is set.

How can I achive this on Android 7+?

Comment: Please check maybe it's necessary to take run time permission.

Answer (score 0):

I never use your code for vibration, but I guess my code below works for Android 7+ (not tested)

Try:

```
 import android.os.Vibrator;

 [...]

 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
 v.vibrate(500);
```

**Note:** It is better to check if your device can vibrate:

```
if (v.hasVibrator()) {
    Log.v("Can Vibrate", "YES");
} else {
    Log.v("Can Vibrate", "NO");
}
```

For more explanation, take a look to a more [precisely answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17066803) by *Liam George Betsworth*.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I don't want to make the device to vibrate from my App. I want to enable/disable vibration in the main device settings. Like sound on, off or only vibration.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 7 you need the permission to change the device settings to toggle any setting parameter.
You can see the option to grant this permission in the App Info.

You will notice a separate List Item named,

`Modify system settings`

[image: Modify System Settings]

and when you click on it, you will be asked to grant the permission or not.

By Default this parameter is set to `No`. Change this and your code will work perfectly.

Or you can add the permission,

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`,

to provide the access by default.

I hope this helps. This option also depends on the ROM you are on.

Answer (score 0):

try this

add permission in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

then code like

```
   import android.os.Vibrator;
   ...........

   Vibrator viber= (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
   viber.vibrate(500); //("time in milliseconds")
```

Comment: I don't want to start vibration. I want to enable/disable vibration in the main device settings. Like sound on, off or only vibration.

Comment: `aManager.setRingerMode(1)`  try this