# Recommended notification vibration duration?

Tags: java, android

What is the recommended notification vibration duration in Android?
Here's my current code which makes a notification vibrate for 1000ms

```
notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] {0,1000});
```

Is there something like `notificationBuilder.setVibrate("default_time");`

Comment: From what I can see many answers have between 400ms-500ms for a single vibrate, lower if multiple in a row (e.g. 200, 200, 200).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default values can be utilized as below -

```
NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
Notification note = mBuilder.build();
note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

or you can also do

```
mBuilder.setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_VIBRATE | DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
```