# how to set vibrate animation and device vibration to edittext?

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext, vibration

**What i want :** I want to create a edit text that will vibrate if given input is empty or invalid.

**Example :** In login screen the password edit text is empty or invalid, than edit text will vibrate at the same time my android device need to vibrate for some time how to create that it?
thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: what is a problem for you: to check if edittext is empty, or to vibrate

Comment: i tried to set the edittext vibrate and got it. now need to set the android device vibration

Comment: if my edittext is empty i need to set android device vibrate and edittext vibrate @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: try searching on google before asking question https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950364/5148289

Comment: So is it a problem for you to determine if the edittext is empty? Or to vibrate?

Comment: also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45605249/5148289) since `Vibrate` is deprecated

Comment: Thank you @V-rundPuro-hit. this is what is already got. But what am looking is , randomly am getting permission error in below android version  i tried with android 5 below verisons

Comment: yeah. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: you should include all this in your question. like what you have done and what specific problem you are facing. that way you will get your answer quickly and easily

Comment: Okay. @V-rundPuro-hit

Comment: you can't answer `yeah` to `this or that` question.

Comment: if empty , then vibrate.

Comment: have you even tried to read my comments? **Which of 2 parts is the problem for you?** What of those 2 things is a problem? To detect if the edittext is empty, or to vibrate?

Answer (score 1):

Alright here is what you need..

### Vibrate Animation

put these two xml files inside `res/anim` folder

**vibrate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="10"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_5" />
```

**cycle_5.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:cycles="5" />
```

### Vibrating Phone

use these method to vibrate your phone for 500 milliseconds

```
public void shakeItBaby() {
    int DURATION = 500; // you can change this according to your need 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(DURATION, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
    } else {
        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(DURATION);
    }
}
```

and don't forget to put permission in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

### Putting all together

now use them both wile validating your EditText

```
Animation vibrate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.vibrate);

if (paytm_amt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
    paytm_num.setError("Please Enter PayTM Number");
    paytm_num.startAnimation(vibrate);
    shakeItBaby();
}  else {
    // do something
}
```

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

Components

```
 EditText mPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
 Button mLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
```

Android Device Vibration

```
 private void AndroidDeviceVibrate() { // Android Device Vibration
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds only
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
    } else {
        v.vibrate(500); // deprecated in API 26
    }
}
```

Edit text vibrate Animation

```
 public TranslateAnimation VibrateError() { // Edit text vibrate Animation
    TranslateAnimation vibrate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 10, 0, 0);
    vibrate.setDuration(600);
    vibrate.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(8));
    return vibrate;
}
```

Finally,

```
mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String strPass = mPassword.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strPass)) {
                AndroidDeviceVibrate();  // Android Device Vibrate
                mPassword.startAnimation(VibrateError()); // Edit text vibrate Animation
            }
        }
    });
```