# How to vibrate android phone until i click stop button?

Tags: android, button, xamarin.forms, vibration

I am using this library:
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/VibratePlugin

```java
var v = CrossVibrate.Current;
v.Vibration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Vibration function gets only `TimeSpan` parameter. How can I do?

Comment: I don't believe that Android exposes any API for this.  Overusing the vibrator is probably very bad for the battery.

Comment: Any idea for solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17066803/3861756.

It describes what you're trying to achieve.