# Continious vibration without pause

Tags: android, android-vibration

I am using `vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(Integer.MAX_VALUE, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));`
 for vibration. The problem is that vibration lasts only about 1-2 seconds instead of a long time. I have also tried

```
Vibrator mVibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
long pattern[]={0,800,200,1200,300,2000,400,4000};
// 2nd argument is for repetition pass -1 if you do not want to repeat the Vibrate
mVibrate.vibrate(pattern,-1);
```

but this vibrates with breaks, even if I set the break to 0.

Comment: check this out-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate

Comment: @Wini But none of the code in that answer vibrates continuously without breaks

Comment: There may be OS caps on the duration to avoid damaging the hardware.