# How do I vibrate my device on SeekBar Progress Update

Tags: android, seekbar, vibration

So I have a seekbar in my android app.
I want the device to vibrate for (say) 50 milliseconds on each update of the progress value.
How do I do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener) to know when the value changes. And check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950364/10762301) to do the vibration.