# device vibration keeps repeating infinitely

Tags: android, android-vibration

im trying to vibrate device and repeat this pattern for 3 times so in total 6x vibrations. Im using code bellow but my device keeps vibrating infinitely. How to stop vibrating after those 3 repeats?

```
private void deviceVibration (){
   
   long[] pattern = {0, 2000, 1000, 2000,1000};
   vibrator.vibrate(pattern,3);

}
```

Comment: you have the answer below which is perfect but if you want to see breifly https://stackoverflow.com/a/23566943/11647620

Comment: http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/06/simple-android-vibration-application.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Vibrator Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator#vibrate(long%5B%5D,%20int))

> public void vibrate (long[] pattern,
> int repeat)

This `long[] pattern` is an array of longs of times for which to turn the vibrator on or off.
This `int repeat` is the index into pattern at which to repeat, or -1 if you don't want to repeat.

So if you put the 3 it will repeat the 3 index position of your pattern.

```
long[] pattern = {0, 2000, 1000, 2000,1000}; <-- 2000 will be repeated
```

So the pattern is ok, you need to remove one to just vibrate three times and then just change your 3 for -1 to don't repeat.

Comment: so if i change index 0 in pattern to 3 `long[] pattern = {3, 2000, 1000, 2000,1000};` and set `vibrator.vibrate(pattern,0);` it should repeat only 3 times right?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
long[] pattern = {0, 2000, 1000, 2000,1000};
 vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

-1 for to vibrate only as mentioned in the pattern.

Comment: it will vibrate 2 times i want to repeat this pattern 3 times

Comment: @zon1k then use `long[] pattern = {0, 2000, 1000, 2000,1000, 2000,1000};`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should like this

```
long[] pattern = {0, 2000, 1000, 2000,1000, 2000,1000};
vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

As Skizo-ozᴉʞS said accept his answer it is more perfect